# Open a page that redirects without clearing cache

Tags: html, firefox, internet-explorer-9

I've taken over a website that has an index.html page that redirects. This page gets cached. Obviously clearing the browser's cache entirely would solve the problem. Is there any way to go directly to mysite.com and be assured of getting the new page without completely clearing the cache?

I'm looking for something similar to holding shift when reloading a page, only this time for the initial opening of a page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a well behaved web browser encounters cached content, it generally still requests the `head` portion of the cached document so that it can ensure that the content hasn't changed since it was last cached. Just as long as the `last-modified` or `content-length` changes, then you shouldn't have a problem.

Issues arise when your web server has explicitly told web browsers to cache the index page heavilly, or when there's proxy servers inbetween.

I take it you've already changed the `index.html` page but some users are still redirecting?

Comment: I guess there is no way to open a new page the with the same emphasis as CTRL-R will reload a page.  Thirty-six hours later everyone is getting the new page, so it may have been a server issue which I'll look into.

Answer (score 2):

Just have that page send out anti-caching headers every time a user loads it. This will force the browser to get a fresh copy of the page every time. You can do this without affecting the caching of the other pages in the site.

**You can use meta tags:**

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

**In PHP send http headers (You'll have to tell Apache parse the file as PHP)**

```
Header( "Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, j M Y H:i:s" ) . " GMT" );
Header( "Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
Header( "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate" ); 
Header( "Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", FALSE );
Header( "Pragma: no-cache" );
```

**In Apache .htaccess**

```
<FilesMatch "index.html$">
FileETag None
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset ETag
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
Header set Pragma "no-cache"
Header set Expires "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: The problem is I already have users stuck with a page that stays cached.  Because this page redirects, I can't have them reload that page.  I've already replaced index.html with a page which has appropriate headers, I just can't get some users to see it because they can't stay on that page to reload it.  Is it possible to load a page, skipping the cache, or will I have to tell my users to clear their cache?

Comment: Good browsers will notice the page has updated by checking the headers each time the user loads the page. But maybe as a temporary solution you can have your home page be named index.htm or index.php (or the extension of your choice) and have the page index.html redirects to redirect to that. Yes, it's a double redirect, but it works around your issue until you can be reasonably sure no users are using the cached page.

Answer (score 0):

Can you rename the existing index.html file to another default directory index filename, like `index.htm`, `default.html`, `default.htm`, or `index.php`? This won't help when people have `index.html` cached and go to `http://www.example.com/index.html`, but it might help when people go straight to `http://www.example.com/`...